# Not able to get correct results even though mean absolute error is low

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('final sheet for project.csv')
features=['moisture','volatile matter','fixed carbon','calorific value','carbon %','oxygen%']
train_data=df[features]
target_data=df.pop('Activation energy')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_data,target_data,  test_size=0.09375, random_state=1)

standard_X_train=pd.DataFrame(StandardScaler().fit_transform(X_train))
standard_X_test=pd.DataFrame(StandardScaler().fit_transform(X_test))

y_train=y_train.values
y_train = y_train.reshape((-1, 1))

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler = scaler.fit(y_train)

normalized_y_train = scaler.transform(y_train)

y_test=y_test.values
y_test = y_test.reshape((-1, 1))

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler = scaler.fit(y_test)

normalized_y_test = scaler.transform(y_test)

model=keras.Sequential([layers.Dense(units=20,input_shape=[6,]),layers.Dense(units=1,activation='tanh')])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mae',
)


history = model.fit(standard_X_train,normalized_y_train, validation_data=(standard_X_test,normalized_y_test),epochs=200)
```

I wish to create a model to predict activation energy using some features . I am getting training loss: 0.0629 and  val_loss: 0.4213.
But when I try to predict the activation energies of some other unseen data ,I get bizarre results. I am a beginner in ML.

Can someone please help what changes can be made in the code. ( I want to make a model with one hidden layer of 20 units that has activation function tanh.)

Comment: You should compare original and predicted RMSE value as well

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `fit_transform` for test data. You should use `fit_transform` for training data and apply just `transform` to test data, in order to use the same parameters for training data, on the test data.

So, the transformation part of your code should change like this:

```
scaler_x = StandardScaler()
standard_X_train = pd.DataFrame(scaler_x.fit_transform(X_train))
standard_X_test  = pd.DataFrame(scaler_x.transform(X_test))

y_train=y_train.values
y_train = y_train.reshape((-1, 1))
y_test=y_test.values
y_test = y_test.reshape((-1, 1))

scaler_y = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
normalized_y_train = scaler_y.fit_transform(y_train)
normalized_y_test  = scaler_y.transform(y_test)
```

Furthermore, since you are scaling your data, you should do the same thing for any prediction. So, your prediction line should be something like:

```
preds = scaler_y.inverse_transform(
     model.predict(scaler_x.transform(pred_input)) #if it is standard_X_test you don't need to transform again, since you already did it. 
     )
```

Additionally, since you are transforming your labels in range 0 and 1, you may need to change your last layer activation function to `sigmoid` instead of `tanh`, or even may better to use an activation function like `relu` in your first layer if you are still getting poor results after above modifications.

```
model=keras.Sequential([
                        layers.Dense(units=20,input_shape=[6,],activation='relu'),
                        layers.Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid')
                       ])
```

Comment: I just now tried these modifications that you have suggested , but still I am getting incorrect output. Is there any other modification that can be tried? like instead of scaling target_y using MinMaxScaler ,anything else?

Comment: Without having knowledge about your data, it is almost impossible to say, scale or any other parameter tuning is helpful for you or not. Furthermore you should specify what do you mean by incorrect output. There is always a metric that measures how much desired output is far from model output like loss, which you should use instead of telling incorrect results.

Comment: Also when I use relu in the first layer and sigmoid in the second layer, my training loss=0.0445 and test loss=0.1103

Comment: Seems, your metrics improved. However you are not satisfied with the prediction results. Now, you should try to change your parameters, e.g. change loss from `mae` to `mse`. or add more layers to your network and so on.

Comment: the mae loss for my predictions on a new data is coming out to be 145.3105

Comment: Looks like that's a case of overfitting.